# tensorflow Object detection model not working with webcam

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have trained object detection model using tensorflow 2.10.1 in python 3.9. I'm trying to use it in webcam but it gives me following error

[image: Error Screenshot]

This is the code I'm using. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqkISICHH-U) tutorial.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
from object_detection.utils import config_util
import cv2 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(r"K:\new\training_demo\pre-trained-models\ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8\pipeline.config")
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=configs['model'], is_training=False)

# Restore checkpoint
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(r"K:\new\training_demo\models\my_ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite\ckpt-3").expect_partial()

@tf.function
def detect_fn(image):
    """Detect objects in image."""

    image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
    detections = detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
    print(shapes)
    return detections, prediction_dict, tf.reshape(shapes, [-1])


category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap("annotations\\label_map.pbtxt")


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

while cap.isOpened(): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image_np = np.array(frame)
    
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
    
    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                  for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np_with_detections,
                detections['detection_boxes'],
                detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
                detections['detection_scores'],
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                max_boxes_to_draw=5,
                min_score_thresh=.8,
                agnostic_mode=False)

    cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))
    
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this error because the num_classes was not equal to what the model was trained on. After setting them equal everything went smoothly.